# issue of wxpython webview

Tags: webview, wxpython

I am using webview, but come accross some problem,

for the href which should jump to another window. the wxpython webview has no reponse.

for the android viewview, user can override the webview method below, and return false:
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)

But in wxpython, how can I handle it?

in the bellow code, after the webview is loaded, I can't click any href in the view

```js
import AppKit
from wx import wx

import wx.html2 as webview


AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()['NSAppTransportSecurity'] = dict(NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = True)

ex = wx.App()
win = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World")
wv = webview.WebView.New(win)
wv.LoadURL("http://www.jianshu.com/")
win.Show(True)
ex.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please include the code that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to bind a handler to the `EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW` event. THe handler will be called when a link is clicked with a different target window. You can then either open a new window or tab for the URL, or just load it into the current window, or whatever you want.